# Having trouble setting default value of Javascript array

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, variables

I have an array set up that changes the h1 on my site when the user clicks a button. However, on initial page load, the h1 shows up empty. The heading will not actually display until the button is clicked. Was wondering if anyone knew of a quick fix to set the default value of this array so it is not empty when page is first loaded (I realize I could just put text in the h1 in the HTML, but would rather have everything pulled form this array):

```
  var arr = ["Whiskey","Vodka","Rum","Tequila"];
  var index = 0;

  $('.button').click(function(){
    $('h1#heading').html(arr[index]);
    index = (index + 1) % arr.length ;
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

Your array is just fine, what lacks a default value is the `h1`. You can initialize it after the document loads with the following code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('h1#heading').html(arr[0]);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You could trigger the click event right after binding it.

```
  $('.button').click(function(){
    $('h1#heading').html(arr[index]);
    index = (index + 1) % arr.length ;
  }).click();
```

or use `.trigger('click');`